# Failed to connect to service endpoint when reading file from s3 using Spark and Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I need to read a file from S3 bucket into a Spark dataSet. I'm used the correct secretKey and accessKey and I also tried with endpoint configuration but I get this Error :

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
 at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100)
 at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.getToken(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:91)

 ... 74 more



java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: datalakedbr: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 

 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:187)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:111)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$3(Invoker.java:265)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:322)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:261)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSCredentialProviderList.getCredentials(AWSCredentialProviderList.java:159)
```

this is the method used :

```
    parkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local").appName("readFile")
            .config("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", "key")
            .config("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", "secretKey")
            .getOrCreate();
    JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());
    String path = "s3a://bucket/path.json";
    Dataset<Row> file = sparkSession.sqlContext().read().load(path);
```

Please anyone can help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that the problem is with the name of the property.

Check the Hadoop documentation here:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html

It says that for S3A, the name of the property should be **fs.s3a.access.key** / **fs.s3a.secret.key**, and not *fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId* / *fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey*.

Other options are **fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId** for S3, or **fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId** for S3N.

Comment: I am using the [Assumed Role](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/assumed_roles.html#Assumed_Role_Configuration_Options) based authentication, and still getting the AccessDenied error as below. Do you know why this could be happening?


_java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: : org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAwsCredentialsException: SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider: No AWS credentials in the Hadoop configuration_